# "scan.time_increment" in laser scan message publishing

Tags: laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was referring to one  [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Sensors) regarding laser scan message publishing related stuff. I found it could possibly be an error in *section 4.2 Writing Code to Publish a LaserScan Message* in the line 32

```
scan.time_increment = (1 / laser_frequency) / (num_readings);
```

In my opinion I should be this way:

```
scan.time_increment = (1 / laser_frequency);
```

Can someone think of it and confirm it. It is just my doubt that the written heuristic there is not really what *scan.time_increment* variable should mean.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12425/%22scan.time_increment%22-in-laser-scan-message-publishing/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2011-12-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tutorial is correct. From the message definition:

```
float32 time_increment   # time between measurements [seconds]
```

That means that it is the time between each reading, not the time between each complete scan (that's the scan_time field of `LaserScan`). Because it's the time between each reading in the scan, it gets divided by the total number of measurements per scan. Note that this does assume that the scanner has 0 time between completing one scan and starting another, so obviously it may be different for different actual sensors instead of this example for publishing.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-12-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1